# Flask debug mode gives an "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error" when running using python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

So, here's a file I made (flaskblog.py):

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Home Page</h1>"
```

Here's how I first ran it:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py
$ flask run
```

Here's how I ran it in debug mode:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=flaskblog.py
$ export FLASK_DEBUG=1
$ flask run
```

Now I want to run the application directly using python. I first updated the .py file:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Home Page</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the command I used to run the python file:

```
$ python3 flaskblog.py
```

It worked fine. Now I want to run the application in debug mode. So, I updated the file:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1>Home Page</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True) #Added ("debug=True") here
```

Command used to run the file:

```
$ python3 flaskblog.py
```

Here's the error:

```
 * Serving Flask app "flaskblog" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskblog.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 988, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/Flask_Blog/flaskblog.py'
```

I just used "XXX" instead of the actual directories. Any help will be appreciated!

PS: All the code is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo&list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH

Comment: I just followed the steps you mentioned and it works fine on my machine. What OS are you using? Also, did you try deleting the whole directory and starting over from scratch, with a new virtual environment?

Comment: @Sumit I deleted the entire directory and did everything again, but I am still getting the same error. I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I am not using any virtual environment. Should I use one?

Comment: I think you should, it's usually a good idea to use virtual environments anyway as they let you work on multiple Python projects with different dependencies. It's a much cleaner approach overall. Can't be sure it'll fix your problem, but it can't hurt to try.

Comment: @Sumit Just created a new virtual environment and started everything from scratch. Got the same result. Activating the debug mode still gives an error. Everything else works fine, though.

Comment: Edit the file `.../python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py` (use your stack trace to get the full path) and, right before line 176 (the `exit_code = ...` line), add a new statement `print('args: {!r}'.format(args))`, then try again. What do you see in the output?

Comment: @Sumit The path of my flaskblog.py.

Comment: That's weird, I saw `['/path/to/python3', '/path/to/flaskblog.py']` on my system. It looks like it's trying to run `./flaskblog.py` directly on your system rather than `python3 flaskblog.py`. Can you try adding a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) to flaskblog.py, make the file executable (`chmod +x flaskblog.py`) and try again?

Comment: @Sumit Wow! It works! Thank you so much. Why was it trying to run it directly rather than `python3 flaskblog.py`?

Comment: I have no idea, maybe it's a flask version difference? You might need to compare your setup with a system where it runs via python like mine if you really want to find out. Glad it worked though!

Comment: @Sumit can you leave your previous suggestion as the answer to this question? Many people will think this question is unanswered.

Comment: Good idea! Will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like Flask is trying to run `./flaskblog.py` directly for some reason, rather than with the python binary (`python3 flaskblog.py`), which is not working since flaskblog.py isn't executable.

So just add the following line ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) at the top of flaskblog.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

...and make the file executable:

```
chmod +x flaskblog.py
```

Then try again, either with `python3 flaskblog.py` or directly as `./flaskblog.py`.

Comment: How to run it on Docker on Windows? No `chmod` command here I believe? How to run such commands inside container?

Comment: @Piotrek I've never used Docker, but a quick Google search suggests adding `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "flaskblog.py"]` to your Dockerfile might work?

Comment: Yes, I've just found that too. Here is a link: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1482#issuecomment-477437009 Thanks anyway!

Comment: I use a virtualenv and I got this problem too. Running `chmod 644 app.py` solved the problem.

Comment: Anyone running into this problem using Docker and Flask - don't try to run the application directly (`python app.py`). Instead use 'CMD ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--port=80"]` in your Dockerfile (if you're exposing port 80).

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the permissions on the .py file from 775 to 664, essentially removing the 'x' from the permissions.

Changed it from:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu
```

to:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu
```