# solving OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, flask

My app gets the following error. Once I search for a solution it said to add shebang line. But apparently it was there. It should be another problem. I kindly request for help here. So, what's the problem?

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/akalanka/network_attack_classifier/server.py
 * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akalanka/network_attack_classifier/server.py", line 45, in <module>
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 944, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1007, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 332, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 176, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/akalanka/network_attack_classifier/server.py'
```

Comment: Can you post parts of the code?

Comment: This pretty much has to be something wrong with the shebang.  Let's see that first line of your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask debug mode gives an "OSError: \[Errno 8\] Exec format error" when running using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322179/flask-debug-mode-gives-an-oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-when-running-us)